# Please help- I can't figure out whats taking down my server every day

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, apache-2.4, logging

Every day my server goes down - sometimes 2 or 3 times a day. Between 2-15 minutes

I was pretty sure it was due to a type of distributed DDOS or perhaps brute force but using Cloudflare doesn't seem to be enough

If someone can look at these and confirm its apache ( incoming traffic) that's causing the crashes that would be a big help

```
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: httpd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: httpd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 6948 Comm: httpd Kdump: loaded Not tainted 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.1.5 11/28/2013
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Call Trace:
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7ffa5>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7a8c3>] dump_header+0x90/0x229
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dadb>] ? cred_has_capability+0x6b/0x120
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c251e>] oom_kill_process+0x25e/0x3f0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dbbe>] ? selinux_capable+0x2e/0x40
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c2d76>] out_of_memory+0x4b6/0x4f0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7b3e0>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x5db/0x729
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c91f6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x436/0x450
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a18ea8>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99be427>] __page_cache_alloc+0x97/0xb0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c0fe0>] filemap_fault+0x270/0x420
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffc0339706>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50 [ext4]
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99edf6a>] __do_fault.isra.61+0x8a/0x100
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99ee51c>] do_read_fault.isra.63+0x4c/0x1b0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99f5d80>] handle_mm_fault+0xa20/0xfb0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9e32731>] ? sock_aio_read+0x21/0x30
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a4c633>] ? do_sync_read+0x93/0xe0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d653>] __do_page_fault+0x213/0x500
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d975>] do_page_fault+0x35/0x90
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89ac9>] ? error_swapgs+0xaa/0xc0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89778>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Mem-Info:
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: active_anon:878702 inactive_anon:27289 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:0 inactive_file:749 isolated_file:78#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:6602 slab_unreclaimable:10598#012 mapped:30050 shmem:78419 pagetables:6291 bounce:0#012 free:20812 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15324kB min:276kB low:344kB high:412kB active_anon:296kB inactive_anon:92kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:24kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:132kB shmem:132kB slab_reclaimable:28kB slab_unreclaimable:32kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:24kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:39 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3580 3765 3765
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:64680kB min:64000kB low:80000kB high:96000kB active_anon:3381472kB inactive_anon:103448kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:3104kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):312kB present:3915776kB managed:3669344kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:114384kB shmem:302416kB slab_reclaimable:20252kB slab_unreclaimable:33768kB kernel_stack:7120kB pagetables:23420kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:4822 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 184 184
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal free:3244kB min:3304kB low:4128kB high:4956kB active_anon:133040kB inactive_anon:5616kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:258048kB managed:189324kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5684kB shmem:11128kB slab_reclaimable:6128kB slab_unreclaimable:8592kB kernel_stack:2304kB pagetables:1720kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (EM) 1*8kB (M) 3*16kB (U) 2*32kB (UE) 3*64kB (UE) 1*128kB (E) 2*256kB (UE) 2*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (UEM) 1*2048kB (E) 2*4096kB (M) = 15300kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 757*4kB (UEM) 502*8kB (UEM) 400*16kB (UEM) 417*32kB (UEM) 257*64kB (UEM) 91*128kB (UEM) 17*256kB (UEM) 5*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 64868kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal: 223*4kB (UEM) 69*8kB (EM) 33*16kB (UEM) 24*32kB (UM) 13*64kB (UM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3572kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 79172 total pagecache pages
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 1047453 pages RAM
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 78810 pages reserved
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  384]     0   384    13969     4769      34        0             0 systemd-journal
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  386]     0   386    74209     2594      66        0             0 nova-agent
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  407]     0   407    29795      369      29        0             0 lvmetad
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  420]     0   420    12083      592      25        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  534]     0   534    13883      109      26        0         -1000 auditd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  556]     0   556    13203      188      31        0             0 smartd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  557]   996   557     2145       37       9        0             0 lsmd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  558]     0   558    22642      214      47        0             0 rngd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  560]     0   560     5386       73      17        0             0 irqbalance
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  561]   997   561   153256     1595      63        0             0 polkitd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  565]     0   565    57041      438      63        0             0 abrtd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  566]     0   566    56465      370      61        0             0 abrt-watch-log
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  570]     0   570     6796      289      19        0             0 systemd-logind
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  571]    81   571    16620      197      32        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  582]   995   582    30102      122      28        0             0 chronyd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  606]     0   606    90793     6722      95        0             0 firewalld
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1061]     0  1061   108533     2196      45        0             0 rackspace-monit
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1065]     0  1065   145994     3269     101        0             0 tuned
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1296]     0  1296    23245      340      43        0             0 master
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1303]    89  1303    23315      349      45        0             0 qmgr
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1331]     0  1331   120817     3635     109        0             0 rsyslogd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1332]     0  1332    28231      256      59        0         -1000 sshd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1357]     0  1357     6477       52      19        0             0 atd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1358]     0  1358    31598      160      19        0             0 crond
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 1624]     0  1624     3022      169      11        0             0 xe-daemon
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [24548]    27 24548    28355       73      12        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [24727]    27 24727   663068   125770     322        0             0 mysqld
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [27028]     0 27028    13322      143      27        0             0 vsftpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [20795]     0 20795    27552       34      10        0             0 agetty
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [15951]     0 15951   172780    12691     260        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [15952]    48 15952    79019     1410     149        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [15957]    48 15957   888056   174687     748        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [16176]    48 16176   855193   177632     751        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [25271]    48 25271   855272   180205     835        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28247]   993 28247   665696    12110     202        0             0 agent
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28248]   993 28248   228276     3979      63        0             0 trace-agent
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28249]   993 28249   252846     5151      81        0             0 process-agent
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [18206]     0 18206    31372       61      18        0             0 anacron
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28219]     0 28219    28321       54      12        0             0 run-parts
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28223]     0 28223    88040     3622     122        0             0 yum-cron
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [28224]     0 28224    28411       36      11        0             0 awk
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 6903]    48  6903   827221   120930     655        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [21093]    48 21093   829126    97392     555        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 3204]     0  3204    45104      229      45        0             0 crond
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 3206]     0  3206    28321       53      12        0             0 run-parts
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 3221]     0  3221   320000    12911     166        0             0 yum-cron
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 3222]     0  3222    28411       36      12        0             0 awk
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 4189]    89  4189    23271      333      46        0             0 pickup
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 6209]     0  6209     2922       54      11        0             0 xe-update-guest
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 6211]     0  6211    35820      178      26        0             0 crond
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ 6217]     0  6217     3298       27      11        0             0 mkdir
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 25271 (httpd) score 186 or sacrifice child
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Killed process 25271 (httpd), UID 48, total-vm:3421088kB, anon-rss:628616kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:92204kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: dbus-daemon invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=-900
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: dbus-daemon cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 571 Comm: dbus-daemon Kdump: loaded Not tainted 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.1.5 11/28/2013
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Call Trace:
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7ffa5>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7a8c3>] dump_header+0x90/0x229
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dadb>] ? cred_has_capability+0x6b/0x120
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c251e>] oom_kill_process+0x25e/0x3f0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dbbe>] ? selinux_capable+0x2e/0x40
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c2d76>] out_of_memory+0x4b6/0x4f0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7b3e0>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x5db/0x729
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c91f6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x436/0x450
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a18ea8>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99be427>] __page_cache_alloc+0x97/0xb0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c0fe0>] filemap_fault+0x270/0x420
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffc0339706>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50 [ext4]
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99edf6a>] __do_fault.isra.61+0x8a/0x100
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99ee51c>] do_read_fault.isra.63+0x4c/0x1b0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99f5d80>] handle_mm_fault+0xa20/0xfb0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a9c029>] ? ep_scan_ready_list.isra.7+0x1b9/0x1f0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d653>] __do_page_fault+0x213/0x500
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d975>] do_page_fault+0x35/0x90
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89ac9>] ? error_swapgs+0xaa/0xc0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89778>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Mem-Info:
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: active_anon:878702 inactive_anon:27289 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:24 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:78#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:6602 slab_unreclaimable:10598#012 mapped:29995 shmem:78419 pagetables:6291 bounce:0#012 free:21434 free_pcp:202 free_cma:0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15324kB min:276kB low:344kB high:412kB active_anon:296kB inactive_anon:92kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:132kB shmem:132kB slab_reclaimable:28kB slab_unreclaimable:32kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:24kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3580 3765 3765
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:67168kB min:64000kB low:80000kB high:96000kB active_anon:3381472kB inactive_anon:103448kB active_file:96kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):312kB present:3915776kB managed:3669344kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:114164kB shmem:302416kB slab_reclaimable:20252kB slab_unreclaimable:33768kB kernel_stack:7120kB pagetables:23420kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:808kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:156 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 184 184
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal free:3244kB min:3304kB low:4128kB high:4956kB active_anon:133040kB inactive_anon:5616kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:258048kB managed:189324kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5684kB shmem:11128kB slab_reclaimable:6128kB slab_unreclaimable:8592kB kernel_stack:2304kB pagetables:1720kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (EM) 1*8kB (M) 4*16kB (UM) 2*32kB (UE) 3*64kB (UE) 1*128kB (E) 2*256kB (UE) 2*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (UEM) 1*2048kB (E) 2*4096kB (M) = 15316kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 834*4kB (UEM) 536*8kB (UEM) 446*16kB (UEM) 451*32kB (UEM) 263*64kB (UEM) 91*128kB (UEM) 16*256kB (UEM) 5*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 67400kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal: 223*4kB (UEM) 69*8kB (EM) 33*16kB (UEM) 27*32kB (UM) 13*64kB (UM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3668kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 78450 total pagecache pages
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 1047453 pages RAM
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: 78810 pages reserved
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  384]     0   384    13969     4769      34        0             0 systemd-journal
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  386]     0   386    74209     2594      66        0             0 nova-agent
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  407]     0   407    29795      369      29        0             0 lvmetad
Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: [  420]     0   420    12083      5

.....
```

and here's another instance of it happening the same day

```
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: httpd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: httpd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 16132 Comm: httpd Kdump: loaded Not tainted 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.1.5 11/28/2013
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Call Trace:
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7ffa5>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7a8c3>] dump_header+0x90/0x229
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dadb>] ? cred_has_capability+0x6b/0x120
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c251e>] oom_kill_process+0x25e/0x3f0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9b0dbbe>] ? selinux_capable+0x2e/0x40
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c2d76>] out_of_memory+0x4b6/0x4f0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f7b3e0>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x5db/0x729
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c91f6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x436/0x450
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a18ea8>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99be427>] __page_cache_alloc+0x97/0xb0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99c0fe0>] filemap_fault+0x270/0x420
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffc0339706>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50 [ext4]
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99edf6a>] __do_fault.isra.61+0x8a/0x100
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99ee51c>] do_read_fault.isra.63+0x4c/0x1b0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb99f5d80>] handle_mm_fault+0xa20/0xfb0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9a4e49e>] ? do_readv_writev+0x19e/0x260
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d653>] __do_page_fault+0x213/0x500
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f8d975>] do_page_fault+0x35/0x90
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89ac9>] ? error_swapgs+0xaa/0xc0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [<ffffffffb9f89778>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Mem-Info:
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: active_anon:880510 inactive_anon:26048 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:980 inactive_file:1374 isolated_file:40#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:6605 slab_unreclaimable:10583#012 mapped:30569 shmem:78464 pagetables:5854 bounce:0#012 free:21148 free_pcp:583 free_cma:0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15336kB min:276kB low:344kB high:412kB active_anon:312kB inactive_anon:88kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:132kB shmem:132kB slab_reclaimable:28kB slab_unreclaimable:32kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:24kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:40 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3580 3765 3765
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:66092kB min:64000kB low:80000kB high:96000kB active_anon:3388036kB inactive_anon:98532kB active_file:3980kB inactive_file:5876kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):160kB present:3915776kB managed:3669344kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:116456kB shmem:302596kB slab_reclaimable:20220kB slab_unreclaimable:33640kB kernel_stack:5968kB pagetables:21748kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:2088kB local_pcp:168kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 184 184
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal free:3164kB min:3304kB low:4128kB high:4956kB active_anon:133692kB inactive_anon:5572kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:258048kB managed:189324kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5688kB shmem:11128kB slab_reclaimable:6172kB slab_unreclaimable:8660kB kernel_stack:2304kB pagetables:1644kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:244kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (E) 0*8kB 5*16kB (UM) 3*32kB (UEM) 3*64kB (UE) 1*128kB (E) 2*256kB (UE) 2*512kB (EM) 3*1024kB (UEM) 1*2048kB (E) 2*4096kB (M) = 15348kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 1001*4kB (UEM) 609*8kB (UEM) 551*16kB (UEM) 459*32kB (UEM) 277*64kB (UEM) 92*128kB (UEM) 11*256kB (UE) 3*512kB (E) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 66236kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 Normal: 143*4kB (UEM) 61*8kB (UEM) 35*16kB (UEM) 34*32kB (UEM) 12*64kB (UEM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3476kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: 81118 total pagecache pages
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: 1047453 pages RAM
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: 78810 pages reserved
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  384]     0   384    13969     5091      34        0             0 systemd-journal
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  386]     0   386    74209     2594      66        0             0 nova-agent
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  407]     0   407    29795      369      29        0             0 lvmetad
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  420]     0   420    12083      592      25        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  534]     0   534    13883      109      26        0         -1000 auditd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  556]     0   556    13203      188      31        0             0 smartd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  557]   996   557     2145       37       9        0             0 lsmd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  558]     0   558    22642      214      47        0             0 rngd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  560]     0   560     5385       72      17        0             0 irqbalance
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  561]   997   561   153256     1595      63        0             0 polkitd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  565]     0   565    57041      438      63        0             0 abrtd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  566]     0   566    56465      370      61        0             0 abrt-watch-log
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  570]     0   570     6796      289      19        0             0 systemd-logind
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  571]    81   571    16620      197      32        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  582]   995   582    30102      122      28        0             0 chronyd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  606]     0   606    90793     6722      95        0             0 firewalld
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1061]     0  1061   108534     2198      45        0             0 rackspace-monit
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1065]     0  1065   145994     3269     101        0             0 tuned
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1296]     0  1296    23245      340      43        0             0 master
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1303]    89  1303    23315      349      45        0             0 qmgr
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1331]     0  1331   120817     3887     110        0             0 rsyslogd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1332]     0  1332    28231      256      59        0         -1000 sshd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1357]     0  1357     6477       52      19        0             0 atd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1358]     0  1358    31598      160      19        0             0 crond
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1624]     0  1624     3022      169      11        0             0 xe-daemon
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [24548]    27 24548    28355       73      12        0             0 mysqld_safe
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [24727]    27 24727   663068   125773     322        0             0 mysqld
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [27028]     0 27028    13322      143      27        0             0 vsftpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [20795]     0 20795    27552       34      10        0             0 agetty
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [15951]     0 15951   172780    12692     260        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [15952]    48 15952    79019     1410     149        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [15957]    48 15957   888056   187683     770        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [16176]    48 16176   855193   194798     836        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [28247]   993 28247   665824    12375     202        0             0 agent
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [28248]   993 28248   228276     3989      63        0             0 trace-agent
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [28249]   993 28249   252846     5139      81        0             0 process-agent
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 6903]    48  6903   829270   156330     758        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [21093]    48 21093   845510   154373     726        0             0 httpd
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [32719]     0 32719    45104      229      45        0             0 crond
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [32724]     0 32724    28321       44      12        0             0 bash
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [32726]     0 32726    40929      802      35        0             0 python
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  483]     0   483    45104      229      45        0             0 crond
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  485]     0   485    28321       54      12        0             0 run-parts
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  497]     0   497   314045    56125     247        0             0 yum-cron
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [  498]     0   498    28411       36      13        0             0 awk
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 1319]    89  1319    23271      333      45        0             0 pickup
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 2153]     0  2153     2923       60      12        0             0 xe-update-guest
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: [ 2154]     0  2154    44078      214      42        0             0 crond
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 16176 (httpd) score 201 or sacrifice child
Oct  1 12:18:25 flylive kernel: Killed process 16176 (httpd), UID 48, total-vm:3420772kB, anon-rss:678440kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:100752kB
```

I just wanted to add this screenshot from Cloudflare showing an insane spike in requests around server downtime. Seems Cloudflare wasn't able to block all the requests ( Im assuming as the site still went down for a couple mins )

[CloudFlare Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Gpv.png)

Comment: Install a monitoring tool that logs memory, cpu and io of your running processes. Check the logs after the next downtime.

Comment: Also check the access logs of your Apache from the time the downtime starts

Comment: Your virtual machine is running out of RAM. You should look into why httpd is using such large amounts of memory.

Comment: Im using datadog and it shows spikes in mem usage with httpd and/or mysqld processes .. most of the time there is also a spike in incoming network traffic during downtime

Comment: You have OOM killer . Check this article from oracle and find bottelneck https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in one of the comments, the issue is that the server is running out of RAM.

This is a typical *misconfiguration*.

You are hosting a website or otherwise publicly accessible service on the *Internet*.
Any traffic should be expected. There are too many "wild" things out there: scripted malware, bots, "digg effects", targeted attacks.

But under no circumstance, no traffic should lead to out of memory conditions.
The OOM (out of memory) results in Linux searching for the most ["fat" process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first) it finds in order to free up memory.

> Oct  1 07:34:34 flylive kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 25271 (httpd) score 186 or sacrifice child

You probably have over-allocated Apache workers so it's using too much RAM. If so, you probably want to [limit them](https://monicalent.com/blog/2013/03/27/avoiding-the-oom-killer-by-limiting-the-number-of-apache2-processes/) to sane numbers that will better correspond to the actual RAM you have.

If you want to guaranteed prevention of downtime like this, you absolutely want to [configure swap space](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/configure-swap-file-on-centos) as a fail-safe which will extend virtual memory available to Linux. But note that swapping is a slow thing because it is essentially "RAM on slow disk".

#### TLDR

- Set up a swap space that is adequate enough to prevent downtime altogether
- Configure swappinness kernel parameter to e.g. 10
- Watch `free -h` output or otherwise the swap usage. If the server is using much swap, your server is still misconfigured and you need to limit things like Apache processes further.

Comment: This answer really made me re-evaluate things. Its the correct answer. I had switched to MPM-Event in apache months ago. Apparently, the default settings don't work well for my server and went back to prefork. Server hasnt gone down since.